# imu mpu9250 unstable in rviz

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using mpu9250 in a differential drive mobile robot.

i am using this package [jeskesen /i2c_imu](https://github.com/jeskesen/i2c_imu) .

My problem is that the robot is unstable in rvize after launching  imu package although the robot is still at its zero position and there is no cmd_vel. (the robot rotates around its base_link origin in yaw, pitch, and roll.)  and base_link, imu_link, and the four wheels links are rotate also).

Those are the imu outputs  although the real robot does not move or rotate:
[orientation:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uh-uzqkr_eKDhBN-CpDaOwbPJ2ZnIUMs/view?usp=sharing)
[angular_velocity:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FjRt5xQXeDybc8yUDXjYtyKVFbogS3pr/view?usp=sharing)
[linear_acceleration:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vQSf3x3Evyn3OneXCCLM-hUxKgcw0ehf/view?usp=sharing)
[base_link small rotation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cMgSkvrgh7S1CwMVbNuDn4vT3x4FpQkW/view?usp=sharing) this image is screen shot during the rotation or the rotational vibration.

[base link with odom](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cMgSkvrgh7S1CwMVbNuDn4vT3x4FpQkW/view?usp=sharing) >> this image is screen shot during the rotation or the rotational vibration.>>>> in this case I rotated the real robot, then the imu rotated also but return frequently to its zero rotation.

[screen shot of robot with heading but it returns frequently to its zero rotation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CD9Rnt0pcULzD9-rCABXZ3Iw2RRb5Sab/view?usp=sharing)

This is the launch file

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_to_base" 
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link imu_link 50" /> 
    <node pkg="i2c_imu" type="i2c_imu_node" name="i2c_imu" output="screen" >
    <rosparam file="$(find i2c_imu)/param/imu.yaml"/>       
    </node>
```

This is imu.yaml  file

```
imu_type: 7
imu_frame: imu_link
i2c_bus: 1 
i2c_slave_address: 104
fusion_type: 2

mpu9150:
  #Sample Rates  
  compass_sample_rate: 25      # 40
   gyro_accel_sample_rate: 50   # 80

  
  #Accel
  accel_low_pass_filter: 3
  accel_full_scale_range: 8  # 16
 
   #Gyro
   gyro_low_pass_filter: 3
   gyro_full_scale_range: 8   # 16
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359700/imu-mpu9250-unstable-in-rviz/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is unstable because I was used odometry node with Imu

---

Originally posted by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) with karma: 23 on 2020-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0